# Android ViewPager set current element always on center

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need a vertical ViewPager that has selected view always on center.
Something like Android's gallery widget works (selected element is always in center).

I have tried to implement vertical Gallery, but since it's deprecated...I would like to have this functionality via ViewPager.

Is there a way to manage that selected view is always on the center?

Also how to manage scroll amount of ViewPager?
For example...when I scroll trough the content I want to scroll for exactly one element's height.

Also I need mechanism how to define exact amouth of pixels for scrolling list view.
When list scroll I don't want it to only show next item, but to scroll for exact amount of pixels to always show the part of the following item.

Tnx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understund the question. Isn't it as easy as this?

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewager.getAdapter().getCount()/2)
```

About scrolling the pager to an specific amount of pixels, 
You have to signal the ViewPager by calling `beginFakeDrag()` and `endFakeDrag()` on it. After starting a fake drag you can use `fakeDragBy(float)` to drag the ViewPager by the given amount of pixels

Comment: About first part of the answer. I have something that looks like vertical gallery view, there is one element fully visible, and two elements that are partly visible, I need when I scroll that next items takes the exact place of the previous in center. Like gallery widget does, in horizontal way. I hope that I've described it better. I will try fakeDrag method. Tnx